# How to refactor this logic in the template/view to use a single line if statement (AngularJS 1.x)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-if

I am fixing some small issues within our AngularJS application - I've come across the logic below which simply displays **one** link.

In pseudocode style..

```
if (data.serviceId exists in the DOM) {
    display link & populate the href from data.serviceId value
} elseif(commentReply.sender.serviceId exists in the DOM) {
    display the link & populate the href from commentReply.sender.serviceId value
}
```

The code itself in the template looks as follows, how can I amend the code below so it is cleaner and I am not duplicating the line using some form of single line tertiary statement?

```
<a ng-if="data.serviceId" ng-href="/#/profile/{{data.serviceId}}">View</a>
<a ng-if="commentReply.sender.serviceId" ng-href="/#/profile/{{commentReply.sender.serviceId}}">View</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example:

```
<a data-ng-href="/#/profile/{{data.serviceId && !commentReply.sender.serviceId ? data.serviceId : commentReply.sender.serviceId}}">View</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/#/profile/{{data.serviceId && !commentReply.sender.serviceId ? data.serviceId : commentReply.sender.serviceId}}">View</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Display one link and get your `href` value from the controller:

```
<a ng-href="/#/profile/{{ myCtrl.getServiceIdHref() }}">View</a>
```

Then add a function to your controller (following your pseudocode):

```
// inside myCtrl.js

this.getServiceIdHref = function() {
    if (data.serviceId exists in the DOM) {
        return data.serviceId value
    } elseif(commentReply.sender.serviceId exists in the DOM) {
        return commentReply.sender.serviceId value
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Omri this is the better method of the two in all honesty but I just needed something 'quick' so went with the other answer but this answer is good to illustrate the 'best' way to do this